How to pass JSON array as input to GitHub Actions workflow?
I have an array with JSON objects created by a workflow as shown below. I want to pass this to another workflow and run a job for each object in the array using matrix.
[{"name": "test1", "org": "national", "size": "12324"}, {"name": "test2", "org": "national", "size": "5432"}]

How can I do this?
